# Bash number comparision error: line 90: [[: 22: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "22")

Tags: bash, jq

Let's assume `$commandGetEvents` is an array of json objects. I use the following command to extract the event Id, which is a number from 1 - 65 and store it in `currentEventId`. Now let's assume I have another variable called `startedEventId` which holds the value I'm looking for, which is 22.

Here's an example of the data $commandGetEvents contains.

```
[   
  {
        "eventId": 22,
        "Name" : "Bob"
        "Activity" : "Eat Food"
        "startedEventId" : 15
    },
    {
        "eventId": 21,
        "Name" : "Smith"
        "Activity" : "Ride a bike"
        "startedEventId" : 13
    },
    {
        "eventId": 20,
        "Name" : "Tony"
        "Activity": "Print paper"
        "startedEventId" : 10
    },
]
```

eventId is the unique identifier of the json object. & startedEventId is the identifier of json object that caused the current one to take place.

```
currentEventId=$(jq ".[$index].eventId" <<< ${commandGetEvents})
startedEventid=$(jq ".[${eventCounter}].startedEventId" <<< $commandGetEvents)
```

When i echo both statements in a while loop, I get the following output.

```
currentEventId = 1
startedEventId = 22

currentEventId = 2
startedEventId = 22

currentEventId = 3
startedEventId = 22
```

The while loop continues until all elements of `currentEventId` are exhausted.

My problem is when I compare both statements like this:

```
if [[ ${startedId} -eq ${currentEventId} ]] ;
   then
   echo "Equal"
fi
```

I get the following error message:

```
line 90: [[: 22: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "22")
```

Comment: What is `startedId`?

Comment: Please provide a sample value of `commandGetEvents` that, when used with the code you show, reproduces the error; see [mcve].

Comment: Sounds like some unprintable bad data in your variable. What's the output of `printf '%s\n' "${startedId}" "${currentEventId}" | cat -v` ?

Comment: Most likely the variable `startedId` is empty or unset.

Comment: Can you [edit] to show what it looks like with `bash -x`? But I guess the problem is that `startedId` is not defined; the correct variable name is `startedEventid`.

Comment: Changing `-eq` to `==` might be an option but might as well hide the real problem. I'm guessing `startedId` or `currentEventId` contains `"<something> 22"` where `<something>` contains an operator..

Comment: Is `if [[ ${startedId} -eq ${currentEventId} ]] ;` really line 90? I'm having problems creating input that could reproduce the error. I guess I'll have to wait for the debug printouts that's been requested by a few people already.

Comment: I've added the contents of $commandGetEvent in the original post.

Comment: @user9186277 Put the line `echo ">${startedId}< >${currentEventId}<"` just before your `if [[ ${startedId} -eq ${currentEventId} ]]`. Include the output in the question.

Comment: Your `json` data is not valid... [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/) may be helpful.

Comment: `[[: 22: syntax error` This is a syntax error. You have to post an [MCVE]. What is the content of a nonempty line before `if`? Is this the line 90?

Comment: Finally! I can get the same error with `a=$'\01'22; [[ $a -eq 22 ]]` - with an unprintable character before the number that doesn't show in the output. Could you run the script and post a hexdump of the error message? Like `script 2>&1 | hexdump`? `When i echo both statements` What would be the output when you echo those statements and pipe via `hexdump`?

Comment: After fixing the `json` data I'm getting a similar error too. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. The provided "JSON" is invalid as JSON.  Please fix it.
2. When using jq at the bash command line, it's almost always best to enclose the jq program in single-quotation marks; bash shell variables can be passed in using --arg or --argjson.  Consider for example the following snippet that assume `commandGetEvents' is valid JSON along the lines suggested in the Q:

```
index=0
currentEventId=$(jq --argjson index $index '.[$index].eventId' <<< ${commandGetEvents})
echo index=$index
echo currentEventId=$currentEventId
```

3. The part of the question involving `eventCounter` is somewhat obscure, but it looks like the example given immediately above will serve as a guide.
4. Rather than using bash constructs to iterate through the JSON array, it would almost certainly be better to use jq's support for iteration and selection. For example:

   jq '.[] | select(.eventId == 22)' <<< ${commandGetEvents}

yields:

```
{
  "eventId": 22,
  "Name": "Bob",
  "Activity": "Eat Food",
  "startedEventId": 15
}
```

So if you just want the startedEventId value (or values) corresponding to .eventId == 22, you could write:

```
jq '.[] | select(.eventId == 22) | .startedEventId' <<< ${commandGetEvents}
```